# In Html.Telerik().Grid(Model), OnRowDataBound is not firing

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, telerik, grid

> I am using Html.Telerik.Grid(Model) for Asp.net MVC application. Some
>   reason  the client function OnRowDataBound("OnRowDataBound") is not
>   firing in the  following code. I put the break point in the client function and it did not get hit; however, the function onLoad(e) did get hit. Please give me advice what is missing.
>   Thank You for your time !!

```
@(
    Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("SiteGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
     columns.Bound(c => c.EMP_NO)                                                      
             .Title("EMP_NO");
     columns.Bound(c => c.EMP_NAME)                                                      
            .Title("EMP_NAME");
     columns.Bound(c => c.HIRED_DATE)                                                      
            .Title("HIRED_DATE");
    })

    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(200))
    .Filterable()                                     
    .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Enabled(true))
    .Sortable()
    .Footer(true)
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .ClientEvents(e => e.OnLoad("onLoad").OnRowDataBound("OnRowDataBound"))                                                                            
)

function OnRowDataBound(e)
{
    var myNewDate = new Date();
    hiredDate = e.dataItem.HIRED_DATE;

    var todayDate = parseDate(myNewDate);
    var theHiredDate = parseDate(hiredDate);

    var dayDifference = daydiff(parseDate(todayDate), parseDate(theHiredDate));

    if(dayDifference > 24){
        e.row.style.backgroundColor = "Red";
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe that event is for remote binding and not model binding

Comment: I am able to solve it by using  .RowAction(row => { inline logic  }) . 

Thanks JamieD77 for your input !